# How to remove a (corrupt?) windows 7 network location when windows explorer crashes when I try to right-click on the network location?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, network-location

I have a Windows 7 machine and I like using windows explorer's network locations but I now have 2 network location mappings which are corrupt and cannot be removed.  When I try to right click on them to delete the network location the entire windows explorer crashes.  Another odd thing is that that the icon of the corrupt network locations have changed from the typical yellow folder icon to internet browser's icon.

How do I  delete these network locations without having to right-click?

Answer (score 5):

SOLVED: I learned that "network locations" are shortcuts stored in the folder
`%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts` and by simply removing these shortcuts the network locations are gone!